# UIWebView rendered differently than Safari

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, mobile-safari, ios6

I have a very complex external webpage, ASPX with lots of javascript, that works fine in Safari on the iPad, but behaves differently in a UIWebView within my app.

Is there something special I should be doing to make it match the behavior of Safari?

This is on iOS5.1 or iOS6. I've looked at other similar threads but there is little information there and the solutions presented there do not apply to this case.

The delegate, webView:didFailLoadWithError: method is not being invoked. I can initiate the load from a button so its not an interrupted load.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what behaves differently. UIWebView is more strict than safari in some cases.

Comment: Not completely sure because I haven't waded through the webpage source. A page view counter appears as an entry field instead of green text. Buttons don't do anything vs. launching another page. It would be nice if some thread described the differences. Where is UIWebView more strict? Other threads are also short on specifics.